# Spark - Get part-file suffix

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

When Spark uses Hadoop writer to write part-file (using saveAsTextFile()), this is the general format "part-NNNNN" it saves the file in. How can I retrieve this suffix "NNNNN" in Spark at runtime?

Ps. I do not want to list the files and then retrieve the suffix.

Answer (score 1):

The files are named `part-00000`, `part-00001`, and so on. Each of the `RDD` partitions is written to one `part-` file. So, the number of output files will depend upon the partitions in the `RDD` being written out.

You could check the RDD being written for the number of partitions (say 5), and then access the files `part-00000` to `part-00004`.

**Illustration**

Build a DataFrame by querying a Hive table

```
scala> val df1=sqlContext.sql("select * from default.hive_table");
```

Get number of RDD partitions

```
scala> df1.rdd.partitions.size
res4: Int = 11
```

Save DataFrame to HDFS

```
scala> df1.rdd.saveAsTextFile("/process_output")
```

Check HDFS output location

```
hadoop fs -ls /process_output
Found 12 items
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs          0 2018-05-01 08:51 /process_output/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs        190 2018-05-01 08:51 /process_output/part-00000
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs        190 2018-05-01 08:51 /process_output/part-00001
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs        182 2018-05-01 08:51 /process_output/part-00002
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs        190 2018-05-01 08:51 /process_output/part-00003
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs        180 2018-05-01 08:51 /process_output/part-00004
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs        190 2018-05-01 08:51 /process_output/part-00005
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs        190 2018-05-01 08:51 /process_output/part-00006
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs        190 2018-05-01 08:51 /process_output/part-00007
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs        190 2018-05-01 08:51 /process_output/part-00008
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs        190 2018-05-01 08:51 /process_output/part-00009
-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs        190 2018-05-01 08:51 /process_output/part-00010
```

Comment: My question is that I need to find out the suffix(part file name), the moment reducer saves the file (without doing hdfs -ls), in the spark program itself.

Comment: The 'hdfs -ls' output is to just show the 'part-' files after they have been written out. In your code, you can get the number of RDD partitions via 'df1.rdd.partitions.size'. For example, if number of partitions is returned as 5, the part files would be named from 'part-00000' to 'part-00004'. This would be done before you actually write them out.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. But how would I know which reducer is writing which part-NNNNN? For example, I have 5 reduce jobs happening simultaneously. The moment second reducer writes part-00002, how would I know that its part-00002, and not part-00003 or part-00001?

Comment: For that level of detail, you would need to check HDFS and see which parts have been written out. Reducers will finish at their own pace depending upon the node they are executing on, if there were any failures, cluster load etc.